# what's the purpose of the parameters of setBounds() methods in javax.swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've a problem with java code
the parameters of `setBounds()` methods didn't work , No matter how I change the parameters, the execution does not change, OR I Don't know what's the purpose of it, Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Show code please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, can you please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit the question to help us better understand where the problem is? Second, can you show us an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Chances are you are using a layout manager that places your components and that's why your `setBounds()` call is ignored.

Comment: Really someone upvoted this question? It lacks: 1) [mre] 2) Research 3) It's poorly written. Don't try to keep the question at **0** vote count as it only harms OP and the site, making them think these kind of questions are OK for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Don't know what's the purpose of it**
-->

This is a method of the java.awt.Component class. It is used to set the position and size of a component:

public void setBounds(int x, int y,int width,height);
Paramentes Details::
x - the new x-coordinate of this component
y - the new y-coordinate of this component
width - the new width of this component
height - the new height of this component

x and y as above correspond to the upper left corner in most (all?) cases.

It is a shortcut for setSize and setLocation, because This generally only works if the layout/layout manager are non-exist.

For more details, refer the 'https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html'.